# RHEL 7.2 yum install openssl-devel errors

Tags: centos, glibc, rhel7

I'm trying to install openssl-devel on RHEL 7.2 with the following command
yum install  openssl-devel

I got the below error, any idea how to fix this?

````
           Requires: openssl = 1.0.1e-57.el6
Error: Package: glibc-2.12-1.212.el6.i686 (centos)
           Requires: glibc-common = 2.12-1.212.el6
           Installed: glibc-common-2.17-105.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda/7.2)```
               glibc-common = 2.17-105.el7
           Available: glibc-common-2.12-1.212.el6.x86_64 (centos)
               glibc-common = 2.12-1.212.el6
````

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.
my /etc/yum.repos.d/centos.repo was pointing to centos6 repository, after changing it to 7 I could install all required packages matching the RHEL7 release. The below is my centos.repo file.

````
name=CentOS $releasever - $basearch
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/$basearch/
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0```
````

Comment: Why are you mixing packages from RHEL and CentOS? Why can't use use `openssl-devel` from RHEL repos?